# How can I get the id to every checkbox on a page in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, checkbox, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I currently have a script, which select every checkbox on a page and then submits the form. Every checkbox is under multiple divs on the page.

I currently have to sit for a round 3 hours manually fetching each selector for a few hundred checkboxes on a page. I then create a recurring list on

```
this.click('selector');
```

As you can imagine, my scripts are very bulky and pretty unpractical.

Is there any way I can fetch the id for every visible `<input>` with `type="checkbox"`?

I only want to fetch the ids that are visible on the page and click on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the checkboxes have `id` attributes, then it is fairly easy with [`casper.getElementsAttribute(selector, attributeName)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsattribute):

```
var ids = casper.getElementsAttribute('input[type="checkbox"][id]', 'id');
```

The CSS selector works like this:

- `input[type="checkbox"]` matches all `input` elements that have the type of "checkbox" and
- `[id]` further restricts the selection to all elements that have an `id` attribute set (it wouldn't make sense to retrieve `id` attributes of elements that don't have those).

Comment: this works well to view the id :) i get a list of ids like this id1,id2,id3,id4 etc how can i extract each on and use it in a casper.click comman ?

Comment: It's a normal array. You can iterate over that array and use each of those ids to click on the elements. The question is whether you expect to reload the page between each click or whether you can click all of them one after the other and submit the form once. If it's the former, then you clearly need to describe how the page behaves and what you want to achieve.

Comment: can u show me an example i want to click all on after another

Comment: No, I can't, because I don't know how you're loading your current page, whether it is dynamic and whether you can just use `casper.back()`. Please add more information.